# Halting a Process[Task, O] on user input

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz-stream

I am trying to write the following function

```
def haltOnUserInput[O](process: Process[Task, O]): Process[Task, O]
```

which halts `process` when the user sends a line on `stdin`. In this scenario, it is ok to wait for the current computation in the process to end, before ending the process itself.

I have tried the following:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import scalaz.{ -\/, \/-, \/ }
import scalaz.stream._
import scalaz.concurrent.Task

def haltOnUserInput[O](process: Process[Task, O]): Process[Task, O] = {
  process.either(io.stdInLines).flatMap {
    case -\/(o) => Process.emit(o)
    case \/-(_) => println("here"); Process.halt
  }
}
```

And I am testing like that:

```
scala> val oneSec = scala.concurrent.duration.Duration("1s")
oneSec: scala.concurrent.duration.Duration = 1 second

scala> val test = haltOnUserInput(Process.awakeEvery(oneSec)).take(10).map(_.toString).to(io.stdOutLines).run
test: scalaz.concurrent.Task[Unit] = scalaz.concurrent.Task@7a5e41bb

scala> test.run
1000144294 nanoseconds
2000148316 nanoseconds
here
3000130736 nanoseconds
here
4000124898 nanoseconds
5000189134 nanoseconds
6000201269 nanoseconds
here
7000127797 nanoseconds
8000132194 nanoseconds
9000191001 nanoseconds
10000126974 nanoseconds
```

As you can see, the user input is acknowledged ("here" is printed, several times) but the Process is not interrupted. I am not sure if `flatMap` behaves as expected wrt `Process.halt`.

Any take on how to write `haltOnUserInput` correctly?

Comment: What's the actual question here

Comment: @Daenyth I have made the question explicit: how to write `haltOnUserInput` correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution is to use wye.interrupt:

```
val input = io.stdInLines.take(1).map(_ => true)
val dory = Process.awakeEvery(1.second).map(_ => println("Hi!"))
val process = input.wye(dory)(wye.interrupt)
process.run.run
```

Comment: That's nice! By the way, the `.take(1)` is useless here.

Comment: This answer helped me, thanks.  May need this change: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852039/why-awakeevery-was-removed-from-scalaz-stream

Answer (score 1):

Here is my implementation of haltOnUserInput:

```
  def haltOnUserInput[O](process: Process[Task, O]): Process[Task, O] = {
     val stop = Process.constant(()) either io.stdInLines map (_.isRight)
     process.until(stop)
   }
```